# How to add custom css of react-bootsrap component in next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

i installed the react-bootstrap module using the pm command then imported it in my _app.js file now when i tried to change the bootstrap code i wasnt able to do so
my navbar component provided by bootstrap is this

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import {
  Nav,
  Navbar,
  NavDropdown,
  Form,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Container,
} from "react-bootstrap";

import headerStyles from '../styles/Header.module.css'

//${headerStyles.navLinks}

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark">
        <Container fluid>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#">
           <Image src={'/logo.png'}  height = "30px" width="190px"/>
          </Navbar.Brand>

          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
            <Nav
              className={"me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 " + headerStyles.navLinks}
              style={{ maxHeight: "100px" }}
              navbarScroll
            >
              <Nav.Link className={headerStyles.navLinks_l} href="#action1">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#action2">Link</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#action2">Link</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#" disabled>
                Link
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Form className="d-flex">
              <FormControl
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                className={"me-2"}
                aria-label="Search"
              />
            </Form>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}
```

here I want to try to customize the CSS of bootstrap which I tried doing with CSS module but I failed. Then I used a global stylesheet to do so but failed
can someone please help me with this?

global css:

```
.navbar-collapse{
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {

    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: blue;
}

.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav{
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0px;
}

.me-auto{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import global.css after importing bootstrap in `_app.js`

```
import "bootstrap.min.js"
import "global.css"
```

using `!important` is not a good choice. [explanation here](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)